# ASP.NET MVC User accounts, "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm really stuck with this. I'm messing about with an MVC app, and can't get the built in individual user accounts to work. If I start a new project just using the default settings it obviously works. But in my app I get the error

> "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context."

in the `AccountController` when trying to register a user. I haven't changed this class.

I think it's something to do with my entity framework context, but I don't know how to fix it. Currently I have a domain layer that the UI references, then a data layer that the domain references. I have added other functionality with that pattern that all works fine. What do I have to do to fix it? Thanks

EDIT: I'm using Unity for DI if that makes any difference, I have had to add a few mappings to my config files for this but I don't think it's that causing the problem?

Comment: post your model structure or design.

Comment: Sorry but not sure what is useful to post? the AccountController is unchanged, as is all the IdentityConfig file etc. As for the structure, it's as I said above, UI->Domain->Data. Just thought to add I'm using Unity for DI if that makes any difference, I have had to add a few mappings to my config files for this but I don't think it's that causing the problem?

Comment: Hi @Chris , this error is probably caused by having a different DbContext in your project.By default the project uses ApplicationDbContext, check whether your data layer context gets conflict with ApplicationDbContext.

Comment: Go to _Model-->IdentityModels_ and check whether you have `ApplicationDbContext` class

Comment: Yes I do have that class, what do I need to do to get that and my data layer context to play nicely?